# How to Stub functions with .try method in RSPEC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

Doing RSPEC test....

Given I have:

```
ShopifyAPI::Product.all(:params => {:page => 1, :limit => 10, published_status: 'published', fields: 'id,handle'})
```

Then, I can stub it by:

```
allow(ShopifyAPI::Product).to receive(:all)
    .with(params: {page: 1, limit: 10, published_status: 'published', fields: 'id,handle'})
    .and_return( test_data )
```

**BUT** having trouble with **.try(:first).try(:handle)** method as below:

```
ShopifyAPI::Product.all(:params => {:page => 1, :limit => 10, published_status: 'published', fields: 'id,handle'}).try(:first).try(:handle)
```

CODE:

```
# MODEL
def test_product_handle
  ShopifyAPI::Product.all(:params => {:page => 1, :limit => 10, published_status: 'published', fields: 'id,handle'}).try(:first).try(:handle)
end


# CONTROLLER
def test
  @test_product_handle = @test.test_product_handle
end

# RSPEC HELPER
def test_product_handles
  [{id: 536491098170, handle: "awesome-sneakers"}, {id: 536491032634, handle: "cool-kicks"}]
end

# RSPEC

it "assigns value" do
  data = to_recursive_ostruct(test_product_handles.try(:first)).try(:handle) 
  # above returns "awesome-sneakers"

  allow(ShopifyAPI::Product).to receive(:all)
    .with(params: {page: 1, limit: 10, published_status: 'published', fields: 'id,handle'})
    .and_return( data )


  get :test

  expect(assigns(:test_product_handle)).to eq(data) # FAILED
  # BUT assigns(:test_product_handle) returns nil
end
```

Anything needs to adjust/add in my code above for stubbing it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are `test_product_handles` and `to_recursive_ostruct` in your tests?

Comment: test_product_handles is array of hash, to_recursive_ostruct is method for converting hash data to OpenStruct Object

Comment: data => value is the same returned value when running it in actual, as i checked in rails console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
data = test_product_handles.map { |hash| to_recursive_ostruct(hash) }
# => Array of OpenStruct objects

allow(ShopifyAPI::Product).to receive(:all).with(params: { page: 1, limit: 10, published_status: 'published', fields: 'id,handle' }) { data }
```